# How do i get the difference in two lists in C#?

Tags: c#, linq, list, linq-to-objects

Ok so I have two lists in C#

```
List<Attribute> attributes = new List<Attribute>();
List<string> songs = new List<string>();
```

one is of strings and and one is of a attribute object that i created..very simple

```
class Attribute
{
    public string size { get; set; }
    public string link { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Attribute(){}
    public Attribute(string s, string l, string n) 
    {
        size = s;
        link = l;
        name = n;
    }
}
```

I now have to compare to see what songs are not in the attributes name so for example

```
songs.Add("something"); 
songs.Add("another"); 
songs.Add("yet another");

Attribute a = new Attribute("500", "http://google.com", "something" ); 
attributes.Add(a);
```

I want a way to return "another" and "yet another" because they are not in the attributes list name

so for pseudocode

```
difference = songs - attributes.names
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
var difference = songs.Except(attributes.Select(s=>s.name)).ToList();
```

**edit**

Added ToList() to make it a list

Comment: An enumerable. Use ToList() if you need to.

Comment: Sorry Adrian, beat me to it. This is actually a really good answer, been wondering how to achieve this for a while myself. +1

Answer (score 6):

It's worth pointing out that the answers posted here will return a list of `songs` not present in `attributes.names`, but it won't give you a list of `attributes.names` not present in `songs`.

While this is what the OP wanted, the title may be a little misleading, especially if (like me) you came here looking for a way to check whether the contents of two lists differ. If this is what you want, you can use the following:-

```
var differences = new HashSet(songs);
differences.SymmetricExceptWith(attributes.Select(a => a.name));
if (differences.Any())
{
    // The lists differ.
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This is the way to find all the songs which aren't included in attributes names:

```
var result = songs
  .Where(!attributes.Select(a => a.name).ToList().Contains(song));
```

The answer using Except is also perfect and probably more efficient.

EDIT: This sintax has one advantage if you're using it in LINQ to SQL: it translates into a `NOT IN` SQL predicate. `Except` is not translated to anything in SQL. So, in that context, all the records would be recovered from the database and excepted on the app side, which is much less efficient.

Comment: Why did you post this if the other answers that use `Except` are perfect and more efficient?

Comment: If you see it, I posted this before the other answers, and added the comment later, stating clearly that the other solutions are better.

Comment: "I posted this before the other answers." You didn't.

Comment: Yes I'm missing a right parentheses. But look at the post times: mine 27 minutes ago, edited 20 minutes ago; ionden 25 minutes ago; mine 24 minutes ago.But as I can see it's offending you, I 'll delete it.

Comment: The 'but' implies that because you posted it earlier (which you never) that you're exempt from missing a parenthesis and it qualifying as a suitable answer. You're wrong with those times. I can blatantly see you posted it later. Yes it offends me, delete it.

Comment: Even if you did post earlier, if another clearly superior and more correct answer is posted by someone else you should just delete your post.

Comment: No, "but" didn't imply that I had the right to not correct my answer . It meant that you was right regarding the parentehsis but not the posting time. Please, don't blame on me: oddly enough, I know see my answer was posted 32 min ago, ionden's 33 min ago, and Adrian's 34 minutes ago, so mine was last in the row. Can't understand it. And, althought I was going to do it, as Adrian corrected my answer I'm not deleting it. By the way I told Except is "probably" more efficient, but I'll have to give it a try to confirm it.

Comment: Hey, the voting system is here so that people knows which is the best answer. That's why I've voted adrian's. However I think it won't hurt to see a different alternative. Mine have at least one advantage. See my edited answer.

Comment: Wow, this got real serious.

Answer (score 4):

```
var diff = songs.Except(attributes.Select(a => a.name)).ToList();
```