# Compare two List<enum> objects in C#

Tags: c#, list, enums

I've two dictionaries like:

```
Dictionary<string, object> dict1 = new Dictionary<string, object>();
Dictionary<string, object> dict2 = new Dictionary<string, object>();
```

I want to compare them where few entries are `List<Enum>`, how can I compare these `List<Enum>` objects. Please see following sample code:

```
enum Days { Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday }
enum Colors { Red, Green, Blue }
enum Cars { Acura, BMW, Ford }
```

Populating dictionaries:

```
List<Days> lst1 = new List<Days>();
List<Days> lst2 = new List<Days>();

lst1.Add(Days.Monday); lst1.Add(Days.Tuesday); 
lst2.Add(Days.Monday); lst2.Add(Days.Tuesday);

dict1.Add("DayEnum", lst1);
dict2.Add("DayEnum", lst2);

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> entry in dict1)
{
    var t1 = dict1[entry.Key];
    var t2 = dict2[entry.Key];

    if (dict1[entry.Key].GetType().IsGenericType && Compare(dict1[entry.Key], dict2[entry.Key]))
    {
                // List elements matches...
    } 
    else if (dict1[entry.Key].Equals(dict2[entry.Key]))
    {
                // Other elements matches...
    }
}
```

It doesn't match unless I provide the exact Enum i.e. `IEnumerable<Days>` but I need a generic code to work for any Enum.

So far I found following way to compare, but I need a generic comparision statement as I don't know all Enums:

```
private static bool Compare<T>(T t1, T t2)
{
    if (t1 is IEnumerable<T>)
    {
        return (t1 as IEnumerable<T>).SequenceEqual(t2 as IEnumerable<T>);
    }
    else
    {
        Type[] genericTypes = t1.GetType().GetGenericArguments();
        if (genericTypes.Length > 0 && genericTypes[0].IsEnum)
        {
            if (genericTypes[0] == typeof(Days))
            {
                return (t1 as IEnumerable<Days>).SequenceEqual(t2 as IEnumerable<Days>);
            }
            else if (genericTypes[0] == typeof(Colors))
            {
                return (t1 as IEnumerable<Colors>).SequenceEqual(t2 as IEnumerable<Colors>);
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to test whether it's a list of enums specifically? Enums are value types, so you could just test for value types.

Comment: @David, it is not Enums comparison, it is List of Enums comparison, which can't be compared like value types.

Comment: Then surely it's a list comparison problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do i get the difference in two lists in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9840539/how-do-i-get-the-difference-in-two-lists-in-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First get the type of the generic arguments with `Type.GetGenericArguments()`, then you can call `IsEnum` on that.

So, something like

```
var listType = dict1[entry.Key].GetType();
if (listType.IsGenericType)
{
   var typeArguments = listType.GetGenericArguments();
   //if you only have List<T> in there, you can pull the first one
   var genericType = typeArguments[0];
   if (genericType.IsEnum) {
        // List elements matches...
   }                
}
```

In answer to your comment, if you want to compare the 2 Lists, you can do the following. Because you have the lists as object in a dictionary, you're better of creating your own method to check whether each element is the same as the element in the other list, because for SequenceEqual you have to know the type.

```
        var listType = dict1[entry.Key].GetType();
        var secondListType = dict2[entry.Key].GetType();
        if (listType.IsGenericType && secondListType.IsGenericType)
        {
            //if you only have List<T> in there, you can pull the first one
            var genericType = listType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
            var secondGenericType = secondListType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
            if (genericType.IsEnum && genericType == secondGenericType && AreEqual((Ilist)dict1[entry.Key],(Ilist)dict2[entry.Key]))
            {                    
                // List elements matches...
            }
        }

    public bool AreEqual(IList first, IList second)
    {
        if (first.Count != second.Count)
        {
            return false;
        }

        for (var elementCounter = 0; elementCounter < first.Count; elementCounter++)
        {
            if (!first[elementCounter].Equals(second[elementCounter]))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: I've already try it, but didn't find the way to match those List objects. If you know then please write the generic comparison statement.

Comment: @Asim I updated my answer to include the code to compare the 2 Lists

Comment: Stephen: did you run ur code? It won't work as I already tried it.

Comment: @Asim: changed my answer, I didn't take into account you were working with `object` as type. Sorry about that.